# Powershell - Get a List of all Computers with their IP Address and Last Logged On User

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i would like to get in Powershell a list of all computers (in my domain) with their IP Address and the last logged on user, the output should be something like this:

**`ComputerName | IpAddress | LastLoggedOnUser`**

`ABC-123        1.2.3.4     Username`

`DEF-456        5.6.7.8     Username1`

`GHI-789        9.0.1.2     Username2`

I have tried a lot of scripts but none of these worked so far :(
Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
i tried this:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
   Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "$computer" -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
}
```

but i get the error "The RPC Server is unavailable"
if i run the command

`Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "[Computer Name]" -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName`

it works, but shows me only one Computer.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried. Explain what didn't work so we can help you with it

Comment: @Theo post updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the scripts you have found to include the lastLoggedOnUser with the following command, but you would need acccess to the computer to retrieve this information.

```
Get-WinEvent  -Computer (computer name) -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 1 | select @{N='User';E={$_.Properties[1].Value}}
```

Comment: just tried this by using my computer's name but i get "SYSTEM" as result

Comment: The SYSTEM account is the highest privilege level in the Windows user model., Log onto a computer and then run the code with the computer you are logged into.

Comment: what if I want to know without logging in the computer?

Comment: You can run this command from your local computer, In the -Computer parameter you would enter the computer name to find the lastLoggedOnUser